# Why is an ATC operational error called a "deal"?

Tags: air-traffic-control, usa, terminology, faa

Air Traffic Controllers who lose separation between aircraft call that event a "deal". Why?

When the Conflict Alert function was added to the computer system, it reported conflicts to the area supervisor.  Controllers came to know the feature as "Squeal-a-Deal", but no one could ever tell me why they're called deals.

Comment: They are called deals because they are situations which have to be dealt with. They aren't operational errors by ATC necessarily, they could be caused by an aircraft breaking a clearance.

Comment: It reminds me of the idiom, "What's the deal?"; which according to the free dictionary .com is a question asked of someone "to explain what they have been doing...." So as @GdD says, initially its investigational (could be serious or could be nothing), but "what's the deal" must be resolved one way or another.

Comment: For the same reason why further reduction of separation between said aircraft is a *big* deal? j/k.

Comment: I've never heard that term. It must be specific to whichever country you are talking about (the USA?) and the question should be tagged accordingly

Comment: As far as I know Deals are part of the US ATC system.

Comment: @J.Hougaard Yes, USA. The term was popularized by a comedian in the 80ies and 90ies named Jerry Seinfeld. His stand-up jokes often began with "Whats the deal with...(insert topic)." As in, "What's the deal with airline food", which he used as an intro to the subject then proceeded to discuss the topic and develop his joke for the audience.  Also, it can be used if someone is acting in a strange or rude manner, you can say "Whats your deal man?" Which is sometimes one step before a fist fight begins.

Comment: @Devil07 To clarify: I know the term "deal", I have just never heard it in this context before :) I added usa tag to the question

Comment: @J.Hougaard I totally see where you are coming from. If you know the meaning of "deal" it doesn't make sense in this context unless you're also familiar with the idiom "Whats your deal?"  Which, btw, is synonymous "Whats your problem?"

Comment: @Devil07 I once worked for a boss who declared "We don't have problems. We have opportunities to excel." The power of semantics.

Answer (score 4):

The first time some of us heard this term was from a controller at a fly-in breakfast, perhaps in the early 80's.  One of the people in the group asked for clarification, and was essentially told that a "deal" was a "big deal" and that a report had to be written and reviewed, and it had the potential of being a factor in a performance rating.

The "deal" in this case was a maintenance truck which was still on a runway, after a 727 was cleared for takeoff.  The 72 driver saw the issue and delayed takeoff, but it was on the tapes, and there were people in the cab who saw it. So paperwork was filed.

Rumor had it that the processes for deviations were relaxed for the new controllers after the strike/firing of controllers under the Regan administration.